# Core Plot Delegate Functions not being called

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I have been trying to get these data on to my graph, I can see the axis but I am unable to display data onto the graph with these delegate functions for CorePlot. First of all, they aren't being called for some reason... I have included CPTPlotDataSource in my .h file and I have included this in my .m file

```
- ( void ) reloadData {

    if ( !graph ) {

        graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,220)];

        CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame: graph.bounds];

        CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        lineStyle.lineWidth              = 1.f;
        lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor redColor];
        dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

        dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
        [graph addPlot: dataSourceLinePlot];

    }

    graphHost.hostedGraph = graph;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(5)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1010)];

    [graph reloadData];

}
```

these are the functions that are not being called....I NSLogged them and nothing is being printed

```
    -(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
    -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

What I'm I missing??

Comment: I was doing a real-time graphing display but I was not calling reloadData at the correct times..

Comment: As i remember CorePlot caches the values and seems that there was a check if range was changed. You may try to change the range (increase X, then just remove invisible values in your data source)